# Applying different style rules to different elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I have a bunch of unordered list elements that are stacked side by side with each other. To accomplish this, the style rule typically applied is:

```
#slide ul,li{
float:left;
list-style-type:none;
}
```

I need to introduce another unordered list of elements that behave the way the `ul` and `li` element typically do; that is stacked on top of each other but without any list-style-type, and to achieve this:

```
.stack ul,li{
list-style-type:none
}
​
```

The problem is that the styles of stack class for ul,li do not apply and the elements stack next to each other as they are being in the case of ul,li for #slide.

Check it out on this js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/G7JHK/

Are my selectors wrong?

P.S: I have tried this out with class/id and various combination of both but the result is always the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS should be like so

```
ul.stack li{
  display:block;
}
ul#slide li{
  float:left;
}
```

​

Comment: ok, but what about if the ul element is stacked in a div for instance we have something like <div class="dropdown"><ul><li...</ul></div>

Comment: It should work as long as you put the correct class or id on the ul element or you could change it so different things occur

Answer (score 5):

Because of the comma in your selector you were applying float left to all li elements. Try something like this:

```
<ul class="stack">
<li>element 1</li>
<li>element  2</li>
</ul>
<br/>
<ul id="slide">
<li>element 3</li>
<li>element  4</li>
</ul>


#slide li{
 display:inline;   
}
```

This css will make all list elements in the div 'slide' display in a row and all other list elements will continue to display like normal. It saves you having to use two different classes :)
​

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like:

```
ul.stack li{
  display:block;
}
ul#slide li{
  float:left;
}
```

Look at the selectors. You want to select a ul with class stack (ul.stack) and find its child li.

Answer (score 3):

There is problem of your selector. class or id of same element never separated by a white space. They should be with no space and the child are separated by a space but no ',' will not be used there..
So you can try this in your code

```
ul.stack li{
display:block;
}
ul#slide li{
float:left;
}
```

Also you have to place the HTML tag name first and then the preceding attribute.

Comment: @Parijat Kalia have you got it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you selected the ul that is a descendent of slide, but your ul has an id of slide, so it doesnt work, because there is no ul that has a container with an id of `slide`. Also by putting `,li` you are selecting all list items on the page. You want to have `#slide li`, which will only select the list items with a container id of `slide`. You don't need the `#slide ul` so your final code should be

```
#slide li {
float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G7JHK/6/
As an alternative, you could use `ul:nth-of-type(2)` instead of an id to save some space in the html
http://jsfiddle.net/G7JHK/7/